# admin order shipment not save with tracking number

Tags: magento2, sales-order, payment-methods, shipment, new-shipment

When I'm using with payment method COD than shipment is working fine, but when I'm using with Authorize.net than getting below error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back in /vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 3767' in /vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61 
Stack trace: 
#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(256, 'Some transactio...', '...', 3767, Array) 
#1 /vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(3767): trigger_error('Some transactio...', 256) 
#2 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->__destruct()
```

Comment: Yes, I was checked with this but its not valuable for me.

Comment: @JugalKishor - have you got any other solution ?